# ViewSwitcher very slow on first view

Tags: android, viewswitcher

I have a ViewSwitcher that displays views. When the ViewSwitcher starts the initial view does not scroll.

```
    final ViewSwitcher vs = (ViewSwitcher)getView().findViewById(R.id.view_switcherz);

    mEventResource = new AlternateEventResource();

    mViewFactory = new AlternateDayViewFactory(vs, mEventResource, getActivity());

    vs.setFactory(mViewFactory);


    final DayView dv = (DayView) vs.getCurrentView();
    Time t = new Time();
    t.set(setTime.getTimeInMillis());
    dv.setSelected(t, false, false);
    dv.clearCachedEvents();

    dv.reloadEvents()
```

I have an application that uses a `ViewSwitcher`.

When initialising the `ViewSwitcher`, the view that is first displayed when scrolled causes a motion event that calls the `onFling()` method.

However the `onFling()` animation is not performed.

When the `ViewSwitcher` view is swiped to the second view the `onFling()` event starts functioning normally.

What could cause an `onFling()` to be called but simply ignored?

I have traced the code with a debugger and the `onFling()` is called but doesn't actually deliver any animation *but only on the initial view.*

Thanks.
Source that I use can be pulled here  to view problem!

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/yadview/
```

Comment: If you forked that project from google code than recreate your steps and see where it started to fail.

Comment: I have done this, and the fling is called on the initial view when scrolled, but it doesn't actually do anything! Need to determine why the fling doesn't work..... the pulled git repo code doesn't work... so it is a problem with the initial codebase and nothing I have added....

Comment: show your fling code.

Comment: Had a similar problem before. It involved the assets being loaded into `ImageView` being too large (512 x 512) which was more than 1mb when rendered into a `Bitmap`